# aws s3 bucket AES Encryption (non kms) access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have enabled deafult encryption  on my bucket using AES encryption or keys managed by AWS. I'm having issues with uploading files to it. It's giving me access denied.

I am not sure which policy to update to have access to encryption.

Do i place it on the policy of the bucket or the role that the bucket gives access to?

I have these objects:
bucket_a
role_for_bucket_a
policy_for_role_of_bucket_a

This is a policy (policy_for_role_of_bucket_a) attached to a role (role_for_bucket_a)

```
    {
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "my-bucket",
                "my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

bucket_a has the following policy that limits access to specific vpc clusters

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": [
                        "my-vpc"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: should help you https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-error-kms/

Comment: yeah that's for custom kms key. i just need the SSE-S3 amazon managed keys

Comment: did you read the article properly it clearly says default aws kms encryption in the first line of article

Comment: i said im not using KMS encryption read this and see what different encryptions are available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/serv-side-encryption.html

Comment: What makes you think that the `Access Denied` error is related to the Encryption setting? Have you tried changing that setting to see whether the upload then works? The policy you have shown is an IAM policy, not a Bucket Policy -- have you used it anywhere?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes. it was unencrypted and it works and i turn on encryption and then it does not. ive been searching how the policy of a SSE-S3 encryption works because ive only seen SSE-KMS solutions and that involves a KMS policy. so im a little confused as to how the amazon managed key is supposed to work

Comment: Interesting! Using SSE-S3 should not require any additional permissions for the user. What S3-related permissions have you been granted via IAM?

Comment: maybe im doing it wrong then. so basically i have a bucket_a that has a policy condition for a specific vpc (only from a specific k8s cluster allowed) for a put and delete actions. that cluster has a role created that has *Object actions for a single bucket (bucket_a). access id in that pod is allowed to assume that role to access the bucket. i hope that made sense. :D ill update post